# AdvancedInstaller Asp .Net application with endpoints/routes

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, advanced-installer

after configuring my Asp .Net app in AdvancedInstaller and launching the installation, the endpoints are not working.

I define them in WebApiConfig.cs like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RegisterApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/Register/{address}/{port}",
            new { controller = "Register" }
        );
```

When I run it under Visual Studio, it works fine.
Should I set it up somehow in the installer?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not trivial to use an installer to deploy a web app onto IIS. You have to review the relevant part of your installer, or reveal more info by editing your question. Too broad right now to say what might be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you know where is the relevant part of the installer? I'm really new in deploying an installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution here:
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/Mar/27/ASPNET-Routing-not-working-on-IIS-70

The required action is to put these lines under web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="ScriptCompressionModule" type="Westwind.Web.ScriptCompressionModule,Westwind.Web" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```